# Boost::asio concurrency (?)

Tags: c++, boost, concurrency, boost-asio

I am compiling the boost::asio example:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html#boost_asio.examples.http_server_3

It is supposed to be a multi-threaded server implementation.

Now, in the async_read handler I print a message and sleep for 30 seconds. I open localhost in two browsers and see that handle_read is called once, then 30 seconds nothing happens and finally handle_read is called for the second time.

The io_Service.run is called with 5 threads.

Why aren't the handlers called concurrently? e.g. why does it wait for the first handle_read to finish before calling the second?

Comment: Show us your code. My bet is that you don't register a new listener until *after* the sleep.

Comment: Are you initiate new async_read() from handle BEFORE sleep?

Comment: Yes, I am putting the sleep before the new async_read.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/server3/connection.cpp
Basically immediately after the if( ! e ).

The way I thought it works is that this works per-connection. So I want to process the data of client 1, and only receive new data when it has finished processing.
But while it is processing client 1 I want to process client 2 as well.

Comment: And you make it just in one socket? If you have 2 different clients you need 2 different sockets. And for each one you need to call async_read() - so they will be independent.

Comment: In handle_accept:
`new_connection_->start();` is called for every new connection, which calls async_read, then async_accept is called to wait for another connection.
In handle_read (registered by async_read), the request is processed and after that async_read is called again to register handle_read. So the calls are made independently in two sockets.

Comment: In example you changed just handle_read() function?

Comment: Yes, I added only the sleep to handle_read.
The problem came up when we rewrote our server implementation to use asio, we saw that it was never using more than 100% CPU. It was using multiple threads (we're printing boost::this_thread::getid()), but executing sequentially. So we decided to compile the server example to see if it has the same behavior. 
Is it clear what my problem is though? Am I right to say that the calls to async_read are per socket, so that I _should_ call it after processing the data, and that while processing I should get callbacks for other sockets?

Comment: @thelamb edit your question to include the **exact** code you have described that reproduces the problem. It is not easy to guess what is wrong based on a series of comments.

Answer (score 1):

It helps to post code. When I use this modification to the asio example:

```
void connection::handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& e,
    std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
  std::cerr << "connection::handle_read()\n";
  boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(10));
  std::cerr << "connection::handle_read() done sleep\n";
  if (!e)
  {
```

it works as expected, that is

```
$ ./test 0.0.0.0 7777 5 .
connection::handle_read()
connection::handle_read()
connection::handle_read() done sleep
connection::handle_read() done sleep
```

How do you "sleep for 30 seconds"? Perhaps the sleep function you've used pauses all threads in the process?